# How to add rows (with conditions) in an existing csv file using Python?

Tags: python, csv

[image: file1.csv]
[image: file2.csv]

Hi all, as you can see, I have created two csv files where the first six rows of the two files are identical. What I'm trying to do now is to add another two rows in each of the files and make sure the first eight columns of the two new rows are identical across files (like the first six rows) but the last two columns contain some other random strings and floating numbers.

Here's my code:

```
import random
import csv

# Generate 10 rows of random data
data = []
for i in range(10):
    row = {}
    for j in range(2):
        row[f"key{j+1}"] = ''.join(random.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', k=20))
    for j in range(8):
        row[f"val{j+1}"] = round(random.uniform(-1000, 1000), 2)
    data.append(row)

# Write the data to two separate CSV files
header = ["key1", "key2"] + ["val" + str(j+1) for j in range(8)]
with open("file1.csv", "w", newline="") as file1, open("file2.csv", "w", newline="") as file2:
    writer1 = csv.DictWriter(file1, fieldnames=header)
    writer2 = csv.DictWriter(file2, fieldnames=header)
    writer1.writeheader()
    writer2.writeheader()
    for i in range(10):
        if i < 6:
            writer1.writerow(data[i])
            writer2.writerow(data[i])
        else:
            writer1.writerow(data[i])
            writer2.writerow(data[i - 6])
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: I'd like to add more rows where the last two columns are the same in the two files, and my current code can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `data` list. Just generate the data in the loops that write to the files.

You can use one loop for the first 6 rows. This loop writes the same data to both files.

Then another loop for the 2 added rows. This generates the same data in the first 8 columns, and different data in the last 2 columns.

```
# Write the data to two separate CSV files
header = ["key1", "key2"] + ["val" + str(j+1) for j in range(8)]
with open("file1.csv", "w", newline="") as file1, open("file2.csv", "w", newline="") as file2:
    writer1 = csv.DictWriter(file1, fieldnames=header)
    writer1.writeheader()
    writer2 = csv.DictWriter(file2, fieldnames=header)
    writer2.writeheader()

    # first 6 rows are the same in both files
    for _ in range(6):
        row = {}
        for j in range(1, 3):
            row[f"key{j}"] = ''.join(random.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', k=20))
        for j in range(1, 9):
            row[f"val{j}"] = round(random.uniform(-1000, 1000), 2)
        writer1.writerow(row)
        writer2.writerow(row)

    # next 2 rows have the same keys and vals1-6, different vals7-8
    for _ in range(2):
        row1 = {}
        row2 = {}
        for j in range(1, 3):
            row1[f"key{j}"] = row2[f"key{j}"] = ''.join(random.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', k=20))
        for j in range(1, 7):
            row1[f"val{j}"] = row2[f"val{j}"] = round(random.uniform(-1000, 1000), 2)
        for j in range(7, 9):
            row1[f"val{j}"] = round(random.uniform(-1000, 1000), 2)
            row2[f"val{j}"] = round(random.uniform(-1000, 1000), 2)
        writer1.writerow(row1)
        writer2.writerow(row2)
```

Notice also that instead of all those `{j+1}` values in the f-strings, I simply changed the starting points of the ranges so `j` will be what you want.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you so much. What if I need to add more than 2 rows (for example, if I need to add 50000 new rows with the first six columns identical and last two columns different)?

Comment: You can just put the appropriate loops inside the `with open...` block, instead of creating lists.

Comment: The question said the first six **rows** are identical, not **columns**.

Comment: I'm sorry for about the confusion. The example I gave is a bit messy. What I'm trying to say is that for the added rows, the first eight columns need to be identical (i.e., key1, key2, val1,..., val6), and the last two columns (i.e., val7 and val8) need to be different.

Comment: I ran your code and it didn't seem to do what I expected.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what you show in the screenshots. All the keys and values in the last 2 rows are different.

Comment: I assumed the screenshots are the desired results.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar! This is very close to what I need.

Comment: Yes, the screenshot was what I have gotten, and technically I need to add two more rows where the first eight columns are the same in the two files and the last two columns are different. Sorry for being misleading.